# Can you create Instagram's “Structure” effect purely in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, effect, reverse-engineering, instagram

I am trying to re-create Instagram's structure effect within Lightroom, but I can’t quite figure it out. Clarity, Sharpening, and Dehaze were my best bets but things are still very different.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Photo.SE. Can you post images both with and without the Structure effect? Without example images, only people who (a) use Instagram, and (b) can imagine its effect from memory, can help answer your question. But with example images, many more people can help identify the combination of effects, without even having used Instagram at all. Thank you! =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replicate Instagram's "Structure" in Capture One or Photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82829/how-can-i-replicate-instagrams-structure-in-capture-one-or-photoshop)

Comment: @JonathanReez I agree, the question is very closely related to the proposed dupe. But this question asks if it's possible to recreate the effect _purely in Lightroom_, whereas the other asks if it's possible to recreate in C1 or PS. The only answer to the proposed dupe used GIMP, and used techniques (such as layers) to do it, which aren't available in LR. On that basis, I think the questions are distinct.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it's entirely possible. The effect looks to be a heavy tone mapping, which Lightroom can't do exactly. In Lightroom, Clarity, Contrast, and Tone Curve may get you quite a bit of the way there. Also, you may need to add a brush over the entire image and increase those settings on that as well to duplicate/multiply the effect.

Edited to add: You may also want to Google "dragan effect lightroom". It's a method that may produce the effect you want, there are free presets available.